# Compiler Error: No matching function for call to find

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to use vectors as I just started studying but was stuck on this error. I tried to look cpp reference and wrote as on it but still getting error.

```
 #include<vector>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstring>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
{

vector<string> vec;

vec.push_back("First");

vec.push_back("second");

for( int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++ )
    vec.push_back("RepeatTimes");

vector<string>::iterator fp = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "First");


for( vector<string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++ )                  cout<<*it<<" ";

}
```

Error is :

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, const char [6])'
```

Comment: You're missing a `#include <string>`. Also, [get rid of `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is right. Please stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: You need to include `<algorithm>`  It's saying it can't find the function; not that it can't find the string.  You most likely got std::string indirectly from <iostream>.

Comment: `using namespace std` rocks. This isn't in a header - there's no reason to avoid it here. Unless you just like typing `std::` for the hell of it. Also, `for(auto it = vec.begin();...)`

Comment: so <cstring> is not same as <string>?    and why stop using std namespace ?

Comment: <cstring> is for the C library 'str*' functions. <string> is for the C++ std library string functions. Get rid of the namespace so that you are clearly using std::vector and friends.

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to include the `<algorithm>` header where `std::find` lives.

You should also include `<string>` for access to `std::string`.
You most likely included `<string>` indirectly from another header and should not rely on it.

---

Since you are learning, I'll go further to suggest modern alternatives to your code.

1. Instead of pushing elements back one at a time,

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
   vec.push_back("First");
   vec.push_back("second");
   ```

   you can use initialization lists:

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> vec {"First", "Second"};
   ```
2. Instead of using a `for` loop to repeatedly add the same element,

   ```
   for( int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++ )
       vec.push_back("RepeatTimes");
   ```

   you can use the insert method:

   ```
   vec.insert(vec.end(), 4, "RepeatTimes");
   ```
3. Consider deducing type names when they are verbose and aren't adding any readability value to the code:

   ```
   auto fp = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "First");
   ```
4. Use range-based `for` loops when iterating over the entire range of the container:

   ```
   for (auto it: vec){
       std::cout << it << " ";
   }
   ```

Comment: 4. An alternative is using std::for_each with lamda function :)

Answer (score 4):

Adding:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

solved my problem